# how to change zoom center in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I want to zoom to touch location but this code always zooming to center of screen.

```
-(id)init{
 UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(handleDoubleTapFrom:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
}

- (void)handleDoubleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    //CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view] ];
    if(!isGameFinished){
        if(zoomPerformed == NO ) {
            id zoomIn = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0f scale:2];
            id sequence = [CCSequence actions:zoomIn, nil];
            [self runAction:sequence];
            zoomPerformed = YES;
        }else{
            id zoomOut = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0f scale:1.0f];
            id sequence = [CCSequence actions:zoomOut, nil];
            [self runAction:sequence];
            zoomPerformed = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

how can i change zoom origin? i searched but none of the methods worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to move the layer that is being scaled (zoomed) so that the point corresponding to the touch location is in the centre of the screen.

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CGPoint center = ccpMult(ccpFromSize(winSize), 0.5);
[self runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccpSub(center, touchLocation)]];
```

You'd also need to reset the position of the layer when zooming back out.

Comment: with some modifications it worked for me. i changed moveTo with moveBy and take reverse of ccpSub().y,
CGPoint zoomPoint = ccpSub(center, touchLocation);
[self runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(zoomPoint.x, -zoomPoint.y)]];